# How can I enable the Hermes engine in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-hermes

I followed the official docs to enable the Hermes engine in my app but the following always returns false:

```js
    const isHermes = () => !!global.HermesInternal;
    console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>', isHermes());
```

The changes I made are setting the following in android/app/build.gradle:

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]
```

Then I did a clean build with:

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean

yarn android
```

But the console.log always returns false

Comment: did your app show something like https://reactnative.dev/docs/assets/HermesApp.jpg on top right?

Comment: This app has been in development for a while so that's not an option @rishikesh_07 . That's why I try to achieve something similar with the log

Comment: Can you make sure your apk contains all three of `libhermes.so`, `libhermes-inspector.so` and `libhermes-executor-debug.so`? Can you further make sure it does *not* contain JSC? [Here's the logic](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/9b76e217bb16935069f0ea5b60f4c4d9b73f86d6/template/android/app/build.gradle#L205) that makes that happen in the RN template project.

Comment: @thatotherguy How can I check that packages were properly installed in iOS case?

Answer (score 0):

I too got `false` when console.logging `isHermes()`. I realized it was because I was using the normal Chrome debugger(not sure of the internals of why). When I just console.logged in VSCode, I got `true`. There is a [special way](https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes#debugging-js-on-hermes-using-google-chromes-devtools:%7E:text=speed%20on%20device.-,Debugging%20JS%20on%20Hermes%20using%20Google,-Chrome%27s%20DevTools%E2%80%8B:%7E:text=Hermes%20supports%20the%20Chrome%20debugger) (sorry, my 'Copy link to highlight' isn't working, it's about 1/4 of the way down the page) you have to set up the Chrome debugger when you are using Hermes. There seems to be [some trouble with getting it to work](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35600#:%7E:text=Unable%20to%20debug%20new%20Hermes%20React%20Native%20app%20using%20Chrome) with newer versions of Chrome though. My plan right now to verify I'm actually using it is to compare the size of the binary before and after enabling Hermes.